# Is there a command line tool to manage unix signals?

Tags: bash, signals, posix, coreutils

Is there a command runner like `env`, `nice`, `nohup`, etc., that can run a program with modified signals? In my case, I need something to reset `SIGINT` to `SIG_DFL`.

Why do I need this? Because non-interactive `bash` sets `SIG_IGN` for `SIGINT` for background processes and you can't reset it with the shell built-in `trap`: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=573780

upd: in bash 4.3 background subshell does not ignore SIGINT, other background programs still do

http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES

> h. Fixed a bug that caused SIGINT and SIGQUIT to not be trappable in
>     asynchronous subshell commands.

Comment: So why not just background the subshell?

Comment: @mikeserv I'm on rhel 6 with bash 4.1

Comment: ...so update? Or maybe get a better shell.

Comment: @mikeserv yeh or he could just install windows and be happy double-clicking stuff instead of writing shell script. Or not doing that at all. I'm pretty sure the OP has his own reason for not changing the operating system or the shell, and it may be better to stay on topic.

Comment: @pgnet - who suggested the os should be changed? And op probably need not even install anything at all to use a better shell - I'm willing to bet `dash` is already installed on the system.

Comment: @mikeserv dash is installed, so what?

Comment: so why not use it? It is *much* faster, more standards compliant, and probably doesn't have the same problem - `bash` has been breaking POSIX compliance where `trap`s are concerned for quite some time now. And I mean that you can *use* it *alongside* `bash` - you can use `dash` to dispatch backgrounded processes for you.

Comment: @mikesev Tested `dash`: it behaves exactly as bash 4.1. `bash has been breaking POSIX`, good to hear: there are many crappy parts in posix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no. Very easy to write one with perl. Here's `untrap` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$SIG{INT} = "DEFAULT";
exec { $ARGV[0] } @ARGV or die "couldn't exec $ARGV[0]: $!";
```

Example usage:

```
#!/bin/bash
untrap bash -c '
    sleep 3
    echo aaa
' &
trap '' INT
wait $!
```

If you remove `untrap` prefix, Ctrl-C won't kill the script.

More versatile script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Getopt::Long;

GetOptions(
    'help' => sub {
        print "usage: $0 [--sig={INT|HUP|...}={IGNORE|DEFAULT}]... COMMAND [ARG]...\n";
        exit 0;
    },
    'sig=s%' =>
    sub {
        my $action = $_[2];
        my $signame = $_[1];
        die "bad action $action" unless ($action eq "IGNORE" or $action eq "DEFAULT");
        die "bad signame $signame" if ($signame eq "__DIE__" or $signame eq "__WARN__");
        $SIG{$_[1]} = $action;
    }) or exit 1;

exec { $ARGV[0] } @ARGV or die "couldn't exec $ARGV[0]: $!";
```

Comment: And the called process sets up it's own signal handlers. You are setting signal handlers for the *Perl* process.

Comment: @vonbrand the called process inherits the "ignore" flag for a signal.